# How to make sure activity show alert on exiting in onPause/onStop (Backpress is handled ) in current android version

Tags: android, android-homebutton

How to make sure activity show alert on exiting in onPause/onStop (Backpress is handled ) in current android version. I have a scenario where user need to give some assessment i need to make sure that a alert is shown to user before he leaves the assessment. I have seen few example on internet mostly people talking about backpressed/KEYGUARD but i need to show a dialog if user is mistakely clicked the home button or trying to exit the activity.

Below code didnt help

```
new OnKeyListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME){
                        //do something
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Comment: Do you want the user to stay on the same activity, even if they mistakenly press the home button? According to the Android Docs, The Home key is handled by the framework and is never delivered to applications.

Comment: nope just alert him and save the data

Comment: You can Save the data, on Home Keypress. To show a dialog, you will have to do it out of the application context, because home key will take the user to the main screen.

Comment: how to do this scenario i m actually a bit confused here

Comment: its the assessment so someone can cheat by putting app in background or there might be some genuine case where apps goes in background mistakely

Comment: Let us understand the scenario. When the user triggers the home button, the current activity closes. The user is taken to the main screen. At this stage, your activity is in the background. Your activity cannot trigger a dialog because the control is given to the Android OS. Essentially, you cannot force the user to stay in your Activity, after they have pressed the home button. As soon as the user triggers it, the control is given to Android and there is no way to override that.

Comment: I can recommend a workaround: You can check the timestamp between the interval. If the user is gone for a long time (Threshold), then you can say that he/she is cheating. You will also have to consider the frequency of these events. If the user does it too many times, it is suspicious.

Comment: ohh technically there is no way to handle this and i have stop assesment right there when the home button is clicked ... thats sound awfull to users ...thanks for confirmation

Comment: No Problem! Good Luck! (Y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Save the data, on Home Keypress. To show a dialog, you will have to do it out of the application context, because the home key will take the user to the main screen. When the user triggers the home button, the current activity closes. The user is taken to the main screen. At this stage, your activity is in the background. Your activity cannot trigger a dialog because the control is given to the Android OS.

According to the [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_HOME), The Home key is handled by the framework and is never delivered to applications.

Essentially, you cannot force the user to stay in your Activity, after they have pressed the home button. As soon as the user triggers it, the control is given to Android. Speaking in context of your application, there is no way to override that.